# Which is better for building chatbot

Tags: chatbot

I need to build a chatbot . so should I build one in Python or should I use dialogueFlow

I tried building with DialogFLow , but at times I get stuck in identifying the langauge of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of chatbot platforms and NLP engines from which you can try from.
Few of them are : Dialogflow, Amazon Lex, LUIS, Chatfuel, Botsify, Beep-boop, Motion.ai, QnA maker, Recast.ai, Octane.ai etc.

It all comes to your requirement and trying out what suits you better.